# What are the differences in selection table data in Raven Pro versus Raven Lite when labeling vocalizations?

Tags: machine-learning, raven

For the purposes of creating a library of labeled vocalizations for suite of species to use in a machine learning algorithm - is there a difference in using Raven Lite versus Raven Pro in terms of the data stored in the selection table? Put another way, is it okay to use Raven Lite for this purpose or is there a feature in Raven Pro that is important? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome @Amanda! I edited the title of your question a bit to make it more detailed/specific and better fit the SE Q/A format. I hope to have maintained the essence of your question, but if not, please comment here or edit back. For more info see: [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title)

Answer (score 7):

The most important limitation I have found in Raven Lite is the inability to add a label column. If you have more than one class of signal you want to annotate (lets say 2 or more species or calls from males and females) you cannot do that with Raven Lite.

Answer (score 2):

Raven Lite selection tables have one automated measurement ("Avg Power Density") and one annotation column.

In contrast Raven Pro allows the user to add many annotation columns and has many optional automated measurements, including those detailed in:

- [Raven Pro User's Manual](https://ravensoundsoftware.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Raven14UsersManual.pdf) pages 166 - 178
- [New Measurements](https://ravensoundsoftware.com/knowledge-base/new-measurements-in-raven-pro-1-5/)